# Stop saving in cache memory Flutter web Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I designed a web app using the Flutter web. I hosted it with Firebase host. But It's not showing changes of my code after deploying to firebase. It's still showing my older version of web app. But I can overcome this problem by clearing cache memory of browser or `ctrl+refresh`. But I don't want to do this every time I deploy to firebase. How to stop saving my web app in cache memory?

hosted link: https://frcovid19dashboard.web.app

Comment: Thank you so much for your question, this is exactly what I was looking for. And the website is awesome like the progressive design and speed , really beautiful work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Append a version number to your main.dart file. Every time you do changes that require the browser to clear cash, change the appended version number before you upload changes so the browser knows something has change and it needs to clear the cash. For example:

First Version:

`<script src="main.dart.js?version=1" type="application/javascript"></script>`

Next time you make changes:

`<script src="main.dart.js?version=2" type="application/javascript"></script>`

And so on. Check this [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/caching-in-flutter-for-web-42b3ae0e348f).

Comment: This is not working for me. Is there another approach?

Comment: @GustavoContreiras Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/65110613/13617136

Comment: where do i put this? because when i put this and deploy into server it will return error 404 since it cannot detect the js file https://urlname.com/main.dart.js?version =1

Comment: you add it on the `index.html` file `scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js' + "?version=" +  getRelease();`, Thank you @unbalanced_equation. I had so much headache trying to figure it out why the release wasn't updating and it is such an easy fix. `getRelease()` is a method that I have that gets the release number when the app is deployed.

Comment: if you're deploying using nginx you can add a `default.conf.template` file with a `sub_filter` that gets the release number from a Environment Variable and add it to header of the index.html file then make a javascript function querying the header `document.querySelector('meta[name="RELEASE_NAME"]')` but that's another topic.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach would be to prevent caching via HTTP headers.
For Firebase Hosting that would be : https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers

I guess you could set up something like this inside the site entry in your `firebase.json`:

```json
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "no-cache"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: for those who are wondering where to add it, It took quite a minute too xD, add this into your ```firebase.json``` file in your fluutter project. Thanks @klydra

Comment: Added it to the post. Glad it helped @ManishKumar :D

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: In light of the discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547 it might be worth replacing the line `"value": "no-cache"` from this answer with `"value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"`.

Comment: It is still not working for me