# Firebase Hosting Flutter Web App not clearing Cache of first deploy

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, caching, hosting

We build a flutter web app and deployed it via firebase hosting. Unfortunately, we didn't configure any caching settings in our initial deploy.

Now we deployed a newer version of our website but people still get the old website shown form the first deploy. What we tried so far:

Adding version no. to our index.html:

```
<"script src="main.dart.js?version=1" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Adding meta Data in our header in index.html:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

In our firebase.json we added the following headers:

```
"headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=10"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

All of these attempts were without any luck. We think that the problem is that the newer version doesn't have those entries in the files. How can we force this to update to our newest version? We even consider opening a new firebase project if that might help.

Comment: do you manage to successfully do this?

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

In your flutter app, in the index.html within the web folder, add a version number after the `src="main.dart.js`

So your new line will look like this:

`<script src="main.dart.js?version=1" type="application/javascript"></script>`

Then increment the version number to 2, etc before you do each build.

**update june 2021:** add this line in index.html as the last script in the body

Comment: thank you, I actually didn't see in docs and just assumed that the new deployed was replacing the one before the messages from terminal are `finalizing version...`, `version finalized`, `releasing new version...`, `release complete`.. just now I realize  "version.." hahah.
Many thanks

Comment: This didn't work for me. It still requires a refresh or two before updating (no difference).

Answer (score 3):

I see Flutter now include this script by default in index.html if project is created recently which has `serviceWorkerVersion` element which updates the version when compiling:

```
<script>
var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
var scriptLoaded = false;
function loadMainDartJs() {
  if (scriptLoaded) {
    return;
  }
  scriptLoaded = true;
  var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
  scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
  scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
  document.body.append(scriptTag);
}

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  // Service workers are supported. Use them.
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
    // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
    // potentially different versions.
    var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
      .then((reg) => {
        function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
          serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
            if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
              console.log('Installed new service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });
        }
        if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
          // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
          // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
          waitForActivation(reg.installing ?? reg.waiting);
        } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
          // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
          // need to ask the service worker to update.
          console.log('New service worker available.');
          reg.update();
          waitForActivation(reg.installing);
        } else {
          // Existing service worker is still good.
          console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
          loadMainDartJs();
        }
      });

    // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
    // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!scriptLoaded) {
        console.warn(
          'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
        );
        loadMainDartJs();
      }
    }, 4000);
  });
} else {
  // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
  loadMainDartJs();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use the server worker caching, you can provide `--pwa-strategy=none`. Otherwise, the app will update after the new version has been downloaded and the page revisited.

#### Example:

**`flutter build web --release --pwa-strategy=none`**

It will Generate a service worker with no body. This is useful for local testing or in cases where the service worker caching functionality is not desirable

By default, it is set to **`offline-first`**:  Attempt to cache the application shell eagerly and then lazily cache all subsequent assets as they are loaded. When making a network request for an asset, the offline cache wil be preferred.

#### Reference:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71333#issuecomment-736732314
- `flutter help build web`

Comment: if i already do flutter build web normally before this, and want to implement this -pwa-strategy=none, do i have to clear the cache first for it to work? or it will work immediately

Comment: @ali You may run `flutter clean` first.

Comment: other than that do i need to change build number everytime i want to deploy new version?

Comment: not necessarily

Answer (score -1):

When you build flutter web then in directory build/web generated a version.json file.
just increase **build_number** and **version** in this file.