# Deployed web app still prints all commented out prints statements in Chrome javascript console Flutter

Tags: firebase-hosting, flutter-web

Today I started diving into deploying my web app to Firebase Hosting.
I so commented out all the `print` statements in my code, run `flutter clean`, then `flutter build web` and then deployed it to firebase.
Now, it all goes smooth except that in Chrome's Javascript console I still get all the prints.

I tried to deploy with no files in the build folder and effectively I got the 404 screen when refreshed the browser, so I'm guessing it has not to do with firebase cache.
What else should I try?
Thank you very much.

my firebase.json is:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "site": "fixit-demo-web",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution here [Firebase Hosting Flutter Web App not clearing Cache of first deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404090/firebase-hosting-flutter-web-app-not-clearing-cache-of-first-deploy/61720981#61720981)
I was missing to give one and update the version in my `index.html` file.