# How to use prevent browser cache with query string if not present before?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, browser, flutter-web

I have Flutter web app which is cache by browser. I need update it.

I see can force browser download new web app if set version for `main.dart.js`: [Stop saving in cache memory Flutter web Firebase hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61286756/stop-saving-in-cache-memory-flutter-web-firebase-hosting)

BUT my current deployed Flutter web app have no version:

```
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

So my question is: If I now add version will this method still work?

```
<script src="main.dart.js?version=1" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Does query string method still work if previous version have no query string?

Comment: Should do as `main.dart.js?version=1` is not equal to `main.dart.js`, and browsers cache on name.  And a query string is part of the name, unlike the # tag,

Answer (score 0):

I used this for my project:

```js
<script>document.write('<script src="main.dart.js?ver=' + new Date().getTime() + '"\><\/script>');</script>
```

instead of this:

```js
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```